# Compile-time AVX detection when using multi-versioning

Tags: gcc, simd, avx

I have quite big function compiled for two different architectures:

```
__attribute__ ((target ("arch=broadwell"))) void doStuff()
{
    doStuffImpl()
}

__attribute__ ((target ("arch=nocona"))) void doStuff()
{
    doStuffImpl();
}

__attribute__((always_inline)) void doStuffImpl()
{
    (...)
}
```

I know this is old way of doing multi-versioning, but I'm using gcc 4.9.3. Also actually doStuffImpl() is not single function, but bunch of functions with inlining, where doStuff() is last actual function call, but I don't think it changes anything.

Function contains some code that is auto-vectorized by compiler, but also I need to add some hand-crafted intrinsics there. Obviously different in two different flavours.
Question is: how can I recognise in compile-time which SIMD extensions are available?
I was trying something like:

```
#ifdef __AVX2__
AVX_intrinsics();
#elif defined __SSE4.2__
SSE_intrinsics();
#endif
```

But it seems that defines comes from "global" -march flag, not the one from multiversioning override.

[**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/z/PXuBci) (intrinsics are garbage, but shows my point)

I could extract this part and do separate multiversioned function, but that would add cost of dispatching and function call.
Is there any way to do compile time differentiation of two multiversioning variants of function?

Comment: `#ifdef __AVX2__` uses the C preprocessor which (logically at least) outputs its result to be read by the compiler proper.  So there's no possible way for `__attribute__` stuff to influence that.  You could maybe pass a compile-time-constant arg that the wrappers pass, so `if(use_avx) { ... } else {... }` will get optimized away.  But GCC probably reject AVX intrinsics even in the `if(false)` branch, causing a compile-time error before dead code elimination can get rid of it. :/

Comment: I'd recommend moving each of the CPU targets to a separate translation unit, which is compiled with the corresponding compiler flags. The common `doStuffImpl` function can be implemented in a header, included in each of the TUs. In that header, you can use predefined macros like `__AVX__` to test for available ISA extensions. The `__attribute__((target))` attributes can be removed in this case.

Comment: @AndreySemashev: Does that work with GCC's `ifunc` dispatching that lets you define multiple versions of the function with the same name?  But yeah that seems like a good idea, or possibly other CPP / macro / `#include` hacks.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, why wouldn't `ifunc` work. You write the function resolver routine, it can return whatever function pointer it wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered in the comments:

I'd recommend moving each of the CPU targets to a separate translation unit, which is compiled with the corresponding compiler flags. The common `doStuffImpl` function can be implemented in a header, included in each of the TUs. In that header, you can use predefined macros like `__AVX__` to test for available ISA extensions. The `__attribute__((target))` attributes are no longer needed and can be removed in this case.